# HackerRank bitwiseAnd challenge - algorithm is too slow?

Tags: python

I am working on this code challenge on HackerRank: [Day 29: Bitwise AND](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-bitwise-and/problem):

> #### Task
>
> Given set ={1,2,3,...,}. Find two integers,  and  (where  < ), from set  such that the value of & is the
> maximum possible and also less than a given integer, . In this case,
> **&** represents the bitwise AND operator.
>
> #### Function Description
>
> Complete the `bitwiseAnd` function in the editor below.
>
> `bitwiseAnd` has the following parameter(s):
>
> - `int N`: the maximum integer to consider
> - `int K`: the limit of the result, inclusive
>
> #### Returns
>
> - `int`: the maximum value of & within the limit.
>
> #### Input Format
>
> The first line contains an integer, , the number of test cases. Each
> of the  subsequent lines defines a test case as 2 space-separated
> integers,  and , respectively.
>
> #### Constraints
>
> - 1 ≤  ≤ 10<sup>3</sup>
> - 2 ≤  ≤ 10<sup>3</sup>
> - 2 ≤  ≤
>
> #### Sample Input
>
> ```
> STDIN   Function
> -----   --------
> 3       T = 3
> 5 2     N = 5, K = 2
> 8 5     N = 8, K = 5
> 2 2     N = 2, K = 2*
> ```
>
> #### Sample Output
>
> ```
> 1
> 4
> 0
> ```

*<sub>At the time of writing the original question has an error here. Corrected in this copy.</sub>

I was not able to solve it using Python, as the time limit was exceeded every time, with a message telling me to optimise my code (some test cases had like 1000 requests).

I then tried writing the same code in C#, and it worked perfectly, executing like 10 times faster, even without any effort in optimizing the code.

---

Is it possible to further optimise the code below, for example with some magic that I don't know about?

#### Code:

```py
def bitwiseAnd(N, K):
    result = 0
    for x in range(1, N):
        for y in range(x+1, N+1):
            if result < x&y < K:
                result = x&y
    
    return result

for x in range(int(input())):
    print(bitwiseAnd(*[int(x) for x in input().split(' ')]))
```

Comment: Indeed, you have implemented a brute force implementation. In my opinion your C# solution should not have been accepted and shows that the testing framework is either not setting strict enough time constraints on C# submissions, or does not include enough tests with large input numbers. The title you have choses is thus misleading: it is not Python that is too slow, it is your algorithm's efficiency that is not good enough.

Comment: RuntimeError is not a TLE ( time limit exceeded), it means that something went wrong while executing the code!!!!

Comment: @oubaydos Which error is thrown is up to the program executing the code to decide. You can't say that definitively.

Comment: Start with largest numbers for x and y. Additionally x and y can't be less than the "result" you already have (because that would result in a smaller "x&y" as the "result" already seen).

Comment: Your `bitwiseAnd` function runs in `O(n^2)` time. The issue is not Python, but the implementation. Instead of trying all possible combinations of values in `S`, can you find an alternative?

Comment: @oubaydos Sorry, I meant `Time limit exceeded` (Runtime error was the "title" of the message box)

Comment: @D_00 ah okay, you should also know that even if the implementation of an algorithm in two languages : c/python per example, was the same, you would find c running faster than python

Comment: @oubaydos I knew that, unless I'm mistaken, Python is written in C, so this goes without saying

Comment: @D_00 yes it is, however, it is interpreted and not compiled, and that makes a huge difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your algorithm has a brute force approach, but it can be done more efficiently.

First, observe some properties of this problem:

- &  will never be greater than  nor than
- If we think we have a solution , then both  and  should have the same 1-bits as  has, including possibly a few more.
- We want  and  to not be greater than needed, since they need to be not greater than , so given the previous point, we should let  be *equal* to , and let  just have one 1-bit more than  (since it should be a different number).
- The *least* possible value for  is then to set a 1-bit at the *least* bit in  that is still 0.
- If this  is still not greater than , then we can conclude that  is a solution.
- With the above steps in mind, it makes sense to first try with the greatest  possible, i.e. =−1, and then reduce  until the above routine finds a  that is not greater than .

Here is the code for that:

```
def bitwiseAnd(N, K):
    for A in range(K - 1, 0, -1):
        # Find the least bit that has a zero in this number A:
        #    Use some "magic" to get the number with just one 1-bit in that position
        bit = (A + 1) & -(A + 1)
        B = A + bit
        if B <= N:
            # We know that A & B == B here, so just return A
            return A  
    return 0
```